# AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.admin' has no attribute 'site'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I encountered the error:

> AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.admin' has no attribute 'site'.

when attempting to get the URL of the Django admin site.

Here is my code in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [

path('', include('adoption.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
urlpatterns= urlpatterns+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, could you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it? This will help us to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `admin` module within `django.contrib`, rather than `django.contrib.auth`, as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects). The `admin` module in `django.contrib.auth` is for customizing authentication, rather than accessing the admin site details.

```
from django.contrib import admin
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```